# cauchy sequence and convergence proof

Tags: real-analysis

Presume that  $(x_n)$ is a sequence s. t.

$|x_n-x_{n+1}| \le 2^{-n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

Prove that $x_n$ converges.

What I've tried to think: since $2^{-n}$ converges to 0, and the difference between the terms $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ is smaller or equal to it, then $x_n$ must be a cauchy sequence and converge. How do I make this an actual proof?

Comment: This is a Cauchy sequence.  To show it, consider $|x_n-x_m|$, add and subtract all intermediate terms, use the triangle inequality $m-n-1$ times, apply the assumption, and compute the value of the geometric sum.

Answer (score 1):

#### Hint:

For $m>n$, write

$$|x_n - x_m| = |x_n + x_{n+1} - x_{n+1} + x_{n+2} - x_{n+2} + ... + -x_{m-n-1} + x_{m-n-1} - x_m|$$

now use triangle inequality

Comment: Am I missing something, or is that supposed to be $-x_m$ instead of $+x_m$

Comment: I fixed it youre right

Answer (score 0):

For each  $n,p>0$

by triangular inequality,

$|x_{n+p}-x_n|\leq2^{-n}(2^{-p+1}+2^{-p+2}...+2^{-1}+1)$
$\leq 2^{1-n}(1-2^{-p})\leq 2^{1-n}$.

and since $\lim_{n\to+\infty}2^{1-n}=0$,

$(\forall \epsilon>0) ( \exists N\in \mathbb N)  : (\forall n>N)  (\forall p>0)  |x_{n+p}-x_n|<2^{1-n}<\epsilon.$

$(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$.

There exists an $N$, such that $2^{-N}<\varepsilon$. (Say $N=\lfloor-\log_2\varepsilon\rfloor+1$.)

Now let $m,n>N$, then
$$
\lvert x_m-x_n\rvert\le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\lvert x_{k+1}-x_k\rvert\le
\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}2^{-k}<2^{-(n-1)}\le 2^{-N}<\varepsilon.
$$